# Alt + Shift + letter in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

In AutoHotKey, this works just fine

```
RAlt & a::Send {U+00E4} ; RightAlt + a -> ä
```

Now I want to map the capital version of that letter, i.e, RightAlt + RightShift + a -> Ä

I tried this but none works

```
RAlt & RShift & a::Send {U+00C4} ; RightAlt + RightShift + a -> Ä
>!>+a::Send {U+00C4}
```

How can I map both

- RightAlt + a -> ä
- RightAlt + RightShift + a -> Ä

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RShift & a` for the hotkey and then check the state of `RShift`.

```
RAlt & a::
GetKeyState,isRShiftDown,RShift,P
IfEqual,isRShiftDown,D
    Send {U+00C4}
else
    Send {U+00E4}
return
```

Another alternative would be:

```
RAlt & a::
If GetKeyState("RShift","P")=1
    Send {U+00C4}
else
    Send {U+00E4}
return
```

In both cases, setting the mode the `P` instead of the default means it will check whether the physical key is being held down regardless of what state the OS thinks it's in. IE, if some other script has `RShift` held down but the key itself isn't held down, these will send `{U+00E4}`.

Comment: thanks a lot, you have an extra `$` at the beginning of the line. Anyway, it works but I can't make `RAlt & a::Send {U+00E4} ; RightAlt + a -> ä` work because AHK does not allow duplicate keys

Comment: I mean, how do you combine with `RAlt & a::Send {U+00E4}`?

Comment: got it, I had to change `Send !a` with `Send {U+00E4}`

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira Ah, yes, sorry! I didn't notice in your question that you wanted `RAlt+a` to send one character and `RAlt+RShift+a` to send a different character. I'll update my answer to show that.

Answer (score 0):

[Custom Combinations](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo) says

> Combinations of three or more keys are not supported.

and

> For standard modifier keys, normal hotkeys typically work as well or
> better than "custom" combinations. For example, <+s:: is recommended
> over LShift & s::

Try also

```
>!a::Send {U+00E4} ; RightAlt + a -> ä
>!>+a::Send {U+00C4} ; RightAlt + RightShift + a -> Ä
```

Instead of sending unicodes you can use the [Text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Text):

```
>!a::Send {text}ä
>!>+a::Send {text}Ä
```

Comment: @João Pimentel Ferreira, is there a reason you prefer custom combinations over the recommended normal hotkeys?